# Fixing panda's datareader from yahoo finance with Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

pandas' datareader from yahoo finance is not working at the moment because yahoo changed the url pandas used to get the data from, yahoo changed it from `'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?...` to `'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?...`.

The error I'm getting is
`IOError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url '...'`

So, I tried editing data.py, according to [this fix](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pystatsmodels/iiqSs79VTXA), but still no go.
I'm using pandas 0.12, with Enthought Canopy.
Do I need to compile something..? is there anything more required?

Comment: Please post relevant part of your traceback (at least url from `IOError: after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url '...'`)
Also be more precise on what exactly have you changed.

Comment: ok, sure, I thought it was merely about asking about how to implement a change in a package's files. I'll edit my question.

Comment: what *exactly* url is in your error?

Comment: it's working now, after I reset Canopy. Should I post an answer or delete my question?

Comment: @erantdo, post an answer and accept it.

Comment: @cyborg I can't, probably because I don't have enough credit. You can post it yourself and I'll accept it, the most important thing for me is that people find this solution, I don't care who'll get the credit.

Answer (score 1):

in (assuming that the user is using Enthought Canopy for Windows, and it's stored in the default location):

`C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\System\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io`

change `yahoo_URL = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?'`

to `yahoo_URL = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?'`

Save and restart Canopy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a current, working version of using Pandas datareader to fetch yahoo quotes:

```
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import datetime

amd = DataReader('AMD',  'yahoo', datetime(2015,7,1), datetime(2015,7,1))
print(amd['Adj Close'][0])
```

Keep in mind that the returned dataset is an array. You need to enumerate said array to get the data, either by specifying your index, or with a for loop

The other keys you can use are Open, Close, High, Low, and Volume.

I have Pandas v 0.16.2

I hope this helps!