# Python: What is the new historical yahoo URL?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, yahoo-finance

I say Python because that is what I am using, but I suspect the issue is more universal.

Error I get when retrieving historical financial data for Yahoo.

> after 3 tries, Yahoo! did not return a 200 for url
>   'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2013&d=0&e=1&f=2014&g=d&ignore=.csv',

I suspect this is a similar problem to [this other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870956/fixing-pandas-datareader-from-yahoo-finance-with-enthought-canopy). In it, the culprit was Yahoo who changed subdomains from ichart.yahoo.com to ichart.finance.yahoo.com.

Comment: What is your version of Pandas?

Comment: have you tried (finance.yahoo.com/charts)

Comment: Using postman, I was able to retrieve the csv more than 3 times

Answer (score 1):

Try the following URL instead.
I've basically copied it from the historical prices link at Yahoo.
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&d=9&e=26&f=2014&g=d&a=2&b=27&c=2014&ignore=.csv